# Auto generate code in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I'm trying to create a SKU code for my database. What I need to do is increment the last value code in my column name `division_code`. My last example code in my column is like this 'DIV343'. When I add a new data, I need to increment the last value into DIV344, but what I'm getting in my column is '1'.

Any help will appreciate.

```
public function save($data)
{
    $data = array(
        'division_name'     => $data['division_name'],
        //'division_code'       => $data['division_code'],
        'division_acro'     => $data['division_acro']
        );
    $this->db->set('division_code', '`division_code`+ 1', FALSE);
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();

}
```

Comment: @BennyHill it's also '1' the output

Comment: @BennyHill it says.Undefined index: division_code

Comment: You have to extract integer from string and then add 1 to that integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to extract integer number from string and then add `1` to that string.

```
$number = filter_var($data['division_code'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

It will give you `343` from `DIV343`.

Now add `1` to this number.

```
$number = $number + 1;
```

If you have `DIV` prefix for all `division_code` then you can use `DIV` directly, otherwise you have to extract string too from original `$data['division_code']`.

Now you can use this:

```
$this->db->set('division_code', 'DIV'.$number, FALSE);
```

And, to extract string too then,

```
$string = preg_replace('!\d+!', '', $data['division_code']);
```

Now add both string and number

```
$final_division_code = $string . $number;
$this->db->set('division_code', $final_division_code, FALSE);
```

Comment: I'm little bit confused, would mine to extract your codes into mine?

Comment: Just extract integer from string.. that's the way how you can add `1` into string having integer

Comment: just few error. I did what you said, but +1 not function. It still div343

Comment: just extract `number` and `string` then add `1` to `number` and finally concatenate both `string` and `number`

Comment: I just need to explore and I got it. Thanks !